# time out for connection to 10.0.2.2:8080 in android

Tags: php, android

I am trying to connect to the php page on my own wamp server using an emulator.
I am not using local host but i am using 10.0.2.2:8080.
this is error is occur.

**1**

```
 06-15 06:40:04.862: V/RadiYo GCM(1334): Posting 'email=dsf@dsf.com&regId=APA91bHKvh5pHc1fef_gyMyD4mDPuMIb0_urES9ZEYOc9F4INS8bNJ3emyleEyboEPRuc6McEqZ6ZmnUOQBLBldCAzDu1IX5NumXO_ZcQ3xxJgptNSnZG1b46dzQ0-On8gPity3XfcE9nWJrTycFt0PvATcQcUCyn8_ZUMrgy_RR2R2i6xiZsXk&name=2332' to http://10.0.2.2:8080/gcm_server_php/register.php
```

**2**

```
 06-15 06:39:43.411: E/RadiYo GCM(1334): Failed to register on attempt 4:java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Comment: Can you access 10.0.2.2:8080 from the browser on your emulator?

Comment: @Ken Wolf  I'm able to connect to google.com but the above ip NO--the screen blurred out but still, it it trying to connect from long time

Comment: From what you describe it sounds like a problem with your server then, not your code. How do you know your server is working fine? Can you access 10.0.2.2:8080 from anywhere?

Comment: @Ken Wolf mine is a wamp server and Im able to access http://localhost from the browser but the same im unable to access using 10.0.2.2:8080

Comment: I could fix this issue
Instead of using http://10.0.2.2:8080
I have used http://10.0.2.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when u running php page check ur server port and replaced it . and also check in manifest file  put it or not if not then go to manifest file and select permission and select internet permission

Comment: here is the config in httpd file
ServerName localhost:80
so the server port is 80, and im unable access it using 10.0.2.2:80/ but im able to access using localhost in the browser